# OrderBy With relationships

Tags: laravel

I have a comments table which in turn can contain replies to comments via the parent_id table.

**Attached, is the migration**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('comment');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('commentable_id');
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();


            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Attached, Model Relationship**

```
 public function replys()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
     }
```

I would like to bring all comments and their replies sorted by `id desc`.

This way I get the parents back correctly but I need to sort the replys as well.

```
$comments = $this->post->comments()->with('user', 'replys')->get();
$comments = $comments->sortByDesc('id')->values()->all();
```

How should I do it? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible to do it in 2 ways:

1 - You can add an orderBy method directly to the relation

```
 public function replys()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id')->orderBy('created_at');
 }
```

2 - You can chain the orderBy Method on a controller or wherever you're using the relation.

```
class Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $replies = Model::find(1)->replys()->orderBy('created_at')->get();

    }
}
```

Please, try this solution and check if it works for you!